# window.location.replace not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Based on my JavaScript code, window.location doesn't work after receiving true response. However I've used possible ways to use it but it seems there's something wrong or maybe I'm doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
  $(function() {
  var url = $(".url").val();
  // start sign up functionality
  $(".signupbtn").on('click', function() {
      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(".toppage").offset().top - 100
      }, 'slow');
      $.post("<?php echo base_url();?>account/signup",
          $("#headersignupform").serialize(),
          function(response) {
              if ($.trim(response) == 'true') {
                  $(".resultsignup").html(response);
                  //THIS SECTION NOT WORKING
              } else {
                  $(".resultsignup").html(response);
                 // THIS SECTION WORKS
              }
          });
  });
  // end signup functionality
  })
```

In the **THIS SECTION NOT WORKING** which I mentioned in above, I've used all these following lines, but it doesn't work after true response:

- window.location.replace(url);
- window.location.href = 'url link';
- window.location(url);
- window.location.href = 'url Link'; return false;
- window.location(url); return false;
- window.location.replace(url);  return false;
- window.top.location = '[url]'
- window.top.location = '[url]'; return false;
- location.assign("url");
- location = "url";
- location.reload(true);

but In the **THIS SECTION WORKS**, all above and following lines codes works. I mean after else means response is false. 
*((I don't need it in false response but it works!!))*

**FYI**, response False and True both of them works well.

**Why I need this?** 
Because after true response I need to reset form fields, for this issue, I also used these following lines, but again not working:

- $('#headersignupform')[0].reset();
- document.getElementById("headersignupform").reset();
- $('form[name="headersignupform"]')[0].reset();
- $("#headersignupform").get(0).reset();

> **Solution**:
>
> I've solved the issue by adding response as HTML into JavaScript not
>   through posted HTML from Ajax.

Comment: Try console logging `response` prior to your conditional in the `.post()` method's callback function.  Is it boolean true or the string "true"?  Comparing boolean true to string "true" evaluates to boolean false, so in that case your `else` condition will be evaluated.

Comment: please, add result of console.log(url,responce) in start of 'function(responce)'

Comment: Please check my updated question in above, thank you.

Comment: <div class='alert alert-success'> You have registered successfully.</div>

Comment: Add your full  html. pleease

Comment: I've updated my question in above, please look for HTML Format Based on console log. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

window.location work if you use code for example:

```
location.assign("http://www.mozilla.org"); // or
location = "http://www.mozilla.org";
```

You can look: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location

Answer (score 1):

`window.top.location = '[your URL]'` is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Below code works like magic

window.history.pushState("", "", "new url");
window.location.reload();